# Bitwise leftshift as power of 2

Tags: c++, bit

Why `x = 1<<n` gives `x = 2^n` ?

I am learning different bit-wise operation and this is one of basic. Can you help me here, what are different bit-wise manipulation I can use?

Comment: The same reason that 1 followed by n zeroes in decimal is equal to 10^n.

Comment: In the binary (unsigned) representation, ith set bit represents value 2^i. When you shift this bit left of n positions, it will become (i+n)th set bit with value 2^(i+n) = 2^i * 2^n. In your case, i is 0, so 2^i = 2^0 = 1, which shifted becomes 2^i * 2^n = 2^n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a binary notation, the position of each digit has a value: 1 for the rightmost position, 2 for the next position to the left, 4 for the position left of that, and so on. When the positions are numbered from right to left as positions 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on, then the value of position *i* is 2<sup>*i*</sup>.

A binary numeral represents a number by multiplying each digit of the binary numeral by the value of its position. So the binary numeral 1101 represents 1•2<sup>3</sup> + 1•2<sup>2</sup> + 0•2<sup>1</sup> + 1•2<sup>0</sup> = 8 + 4 + 1 = 13.

When we shift a binary numeral left *n* bits, each digit is moved left *n* positions (and zeros are introduced on the right). So the digit that was at the position with value 2<sup>*i*</sup> is moved to the position with value 2<sup>*i*+*n*</sup>. Thus, the value for this digit is multiplied by 2<sup>*n*</sup>. The total value of the number is multiplied by 2<sup>*n*</sup>.

For example, shifting 1101 two bits left yields 110100 with value 1•2<sup>5</sup> + 1•2<sup>4</sup> + 0•2<sup>3</sup> + 1•2<sup>2</sup> + 0•2<sup>1</sup> + 0•2<sup>0</sup> = 32 + 16 + 4 = 52 = 13•2<sup>2</sup>.

In a computer, there are a fixed number of bits in an object. If the shift moves some of the 1 bits out of the object, they will be lost, and the new value will not follow this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Because in any binary number,
Let say x = 101 if we do left shift by 1 then x becomes
1010  simply it gets multiply by 2.

Similarly if we do left shift of x by k , then x becomes x*2^k

```
1<<1 = 10 = 2
1<<2 = 100 = 2*2                                                                                   
1<<3 = 1000 = 2*2*2
```

hence `1<<n = 2^n`